# i was deploying my nodejs app on evennode but i am getting this error

Tags: node.js, deployment

i have been trying everything but it keeps throwing this error in the log. and says 502 bad gateway when trying to access the url.

```
 events.js:141
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^
 Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
     at listen (net.js:1270:10)
     at net.js:1379:9
     at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:453:9)
     at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:17)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
     at startup (node.js:139:18)
     at node.js:968:3
```

here's my app.js (also my start script as specified in package.json).

```
 var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


var routes = require('./routes/home');
var users = require('./routes/users');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        io.emit('msg', data);
    });
});

http.listen(process.env.port, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
    console.log('server runninng at ' + http.url );
});
```

although at console(stdout) it says 
-> starting app
-> running server at undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the `process.env.port` to `process.env.PORT` since env vars are case sensitive.

The listen should look like this:

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
    console.log('server runninng at ' + http.url );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Experiment with your code to see what is causing the problem. First try:

```
http.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {...
```

This will solve the problem if it was something to do with your `process.env.PORT` variable.

If that doesn't work, try:

```
http.listen(4000, function(err) {...
```

This will solve the problem if it was something to do with the provided hostname (`0.0.0.0`). The hostname argument in the listen function is optional, so it should be fine without.

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid address to listen to. Try 127.0.0.1 to listen to the loop back on your local machine or get your machine IP address instead.

0.0.0.0 means all ports for routing usually.